# I am not able to fetch the data properly

Tags: laravel-5.5

I am creating a market plus system. There are two different identities - a customer and a seller . I have the following tables- users, products and sellers. On registration all the data is getting stored in users table with the role as a customer or as a seller and if seller its email is even stored in the sellers table having two more columns of market and city. On logging in as a seller i am asking for market and the city and it is also getting stored and after it i am asking  for adding the product details. On logging in  as a customer i am asking for the market and city and i am able to fetch those emails of the sellers with the same market and city but after that i am unable to fetch the data from products table with the same email whose market and city are same as customer's market and city. Why so ??

This is my customer controller-

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Seller;
use App\Product;
use DB;

class Customercontroller extends Controller
{
    public function customerdata(Request $request)
    {
       $c_market=$request['c_market'];
       $c_city=$request['c_city'];

       $data=DB::table('sellers')->get();
       $pdata=DB::table('products')->get();

       $eml=DB::table('sellers')->select('email')->where(['market'=>$c_market,'city'=>$c_city])->get();   //This is working
        $p=DB::table('products')->select('product')->where(['$pdata[0]->email'=>$eml])->get();
        dd($p);  /*But on doing this i am getting an error of Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string*/

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `$eml` is an object. So when you are using it in the where clause as a string, the error is occurring.

You can get the desired result by using `join clause`.

```
DB::table('sellers')
    ->leftJoin('products', 'products.email', '=', 'sellers.email')
    ->where('sellers.market', $c_market)
    ->where('sellers.city', $c_city)
    ->get();
```

This will give you all the products related to inputted market and city.